# CSS: Nested declaration on child element is overridden by its parent nested declaration

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am having problem with nested CSS declarations for nested elements. Emm.. It's really hard to describe the problem, if you don't get what I mean, please just go to the jsfiddle link I provide below, you would understand what's the issue.

Here is the markup

```
<div class="red">
    <h1>should be red</h1>
    <div class="blue">
        <h1>should be blue</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.blue h1 {
    color: blue;
}
.red h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Notice that I put `.blue h1` before the `.red h1` declaration. But I have `.blue` element as a child of `.red` element. Please see the output on the jsfiddle. It shows wrong color on the `.blue h1` element. However if I swapped the declaration into `.red h1` first and then `.blue h1`, it's all fine. But I CAN'T do that in my real case and moreover if I swap the declaration, it won't work if the markup is also swapped. Vice versa.

http://jsfiddle.net/N7FcB/

Anyone got an idea how to solve this one?

PS: I know that having direct child selector will solve the problem. But I avoid to use it, because the element I am targeting (`<h1>`) is not always a direct child of the element with the class.

Thanks before :)

**Update:**
Imagine I have this kind of declaration

```
.red h1 { color: red }
.green h1 { color: green }
.blue h1 { color: blue }
.gray h1 { color: gray }
/* and so on */
```

I can freely create my markup whether it's blue inside red or the opposite or gray inside red which is inside blue. It should work well in any conditions I write the nested markup.

**Update:**
I think everyone does not really get what I am seeking here, please check out this new fiddle, it has better understanding of what I want. the first case is the false one, the 2nd case is the right one.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmMXW/9/

Comment: This is one of the well-known shortcomings of specificity in CSS unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @BoltClock, yeah I think we need "nearest child" selector in next CSS version. I need CSS to detect where declaration is stronger based on the nearest container which acts in the declaration, not by the latest declaration (when we have several declarations considered same strong)

Answer (score 1):

Browser reads your CSS from top to bottom and it will apply in the same way..

So first you have a rule called

```
.blue h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

So browser will parse this information and will color your `h1` as `blue`, but it goes ahead and it hits second selector which is

```
.red h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

Now, as your `h1` which is nested inside `.blue` is further nested inside `.red` and also, the specificity of both the selectors are same, browser will go ahead and apply `red` to the inner `h1`.

So what's the solution?

If you can, just swap the order of your classes... No? You cannot? than use a specific selector..

```
div.blue h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N7FcB/3/)

The above selector is more specific compared to `.red h1` as it has a `class`, and 2 elements... so here, browser will pick up first rule as it is more specific, thus overriding your `.red h1` selector.

You can make your selectors specific as much as you need, you can write the above as `div.red div.blue h1` or `.red .blue h1`, but just remember, the more specific selectors you use, the more you hit performance bar, also you will end up writing more and more specific selectors inorder to override others, so choose wisely..

Comment: whoa, just edited the `specific selector` part few seconds back.. Cool explanation +1

Comment: @NathanLee I decided to drop an answer cuz you had missed that :)

Comment: @NathanLee this answer :P

Comment: Hi, I understand it. But that means you specifically declare taht `.blue` should be more specific. In my case, my CSS will work like a framework. People can freely write the markup, whether it is `blue` in `red` or `red` in `blue`. See this example, http://jsfiddle.net/N7FcB/5/

Comment: hemph, okay I guess everyone is not clearly understand what I am seeking here. Please try this fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/kmMXW/9/

Comment: @DavidRozando I guess everyone cannot be wrong yea :) I've provided you a very neat explanation for this behavior, using only CSS for templating engine won't suffice, you will have to use Javascript/jQuery to add, remove classes/elements attributes which will modify the DOM and apply the styles accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want direct child selector, just add a parent reference for the nested elements.
This will make your thing work.

You can add the below.

```
.red .blue h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N7FcB/1/)**

To enforce your div to render the color blue, you just need to add the reference of the element that you are using to the class.

**for Instance,**

```
div.blue h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/N7FcB/4/)**

In both cases, it will work.

Comment: The 2nd method is same with the previous answer. I think we can discuss it on the previous answer's comments.

The 1st method, it also works but still, I need it to be declared not specifically knowing that blue will be inside the red. Just like the @alien's answer

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe like that:

```
.red > h1 {
    color: red;
}
.blue h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxVcL/3/).

This is 100%.

Comment: Hemphh.. I don't think so.. I avoid using direct child selector.. Imagine I have this kind of declaration

    .red h1 { color: red }
    .green h1 { color: green }
    .blue h1 { color: blue }
    .gray h1 { color: gray }
    /* and so on */

I can freely create my markup whether it's blue inside red or the opposite or gray inside red which is inside blue.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
.red > h1 {
color: red;
} 
.blue h1 {
color: blue;
}
```

select as direct child you will not face any more problem.

Comment: Hi there, I think it's the same with @AlexandreDiacov answer. Please look at my update on the question, I don't want it to be specific as if you know exactly that blue will be inside the red element

Comment: it will be helpfull check it. when ever you are nesting element use the direct child selector in css

Comment: Hi @venu, yeah I understand it, but that's not the problem I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
.blue > * {
color: blue;
}

.red > * {
    color: red;
}
```

You can always try ">" selector combined with wildcard

[myfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9XtaM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
div.red > h1 {
    color: red !important;
}

div.blue > h1 {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

or throw div element

```
.red > h1 {
    color: red !important;
}

.blue > h1 {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N7FcB/6/

Comment: thanks for answering, unfortunately like what I wrote on my question, the h1 isn't always the direct child of the element with the class. it is too specific

Answer (score 0):

Actually how many H1 do you need inside a div? i say not much. so why don't why give the class to the H1.

```
h1.red { color: red; }
h1.green { color: green; }
h1.blue { color: blue; }
```

---

**Update**

How about having a box with depth level, see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AnL7R/

by having linked classes you can override the upper one, e.g:

```
.blue,
.blue.first,
.blue.second
/*more depth class*/
{
    color: blue;
}

.red,
.red.first,
.red.second
/*more depth class*/
{
    color: blue;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @Gabe, I need it because, the div would work as a box with a color palette system. When I say a box has RED color palette, it should change all the style inside him. The `h1` maybe has MAROON color, the normal `p` maybe has RED and the `a` (link) may has PINK. It should work whenever I put the `h1`, `p`, `a`, not always as direct children of the box itself.